# How to get specific data on a unit of dict in json

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a json type data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "library_id": 1,
            "caseinfo_id": 80,
            "caseinfo":{
                "id": 840,
                "patient_name": "John"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "library_id": 2,
            "caseinfo_id": 81,
            "caseinfo":{
                "id": 850,
                "patient_name": "Wick"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want get specific info data, for example i want get the relate info that `patient_name = "Wick"`,so the return data will be:

```
        {
            "id": 2,
            "library_id": 2,
            "caseinfo_id": 81,
            "caseinfo":{
                "id": 850,
                "patient_name": "Wick"
            }
        }
```

Can someone help me on that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get the first dictionary with `patient_name = "Wick"`. If no match is found, we can supply a *default* value of `None`. If no default value is given, this code will raise a `StopIteration` exception.

```
d = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "library_id": 1,
            "caseinfo_id": 80,
            "caseinfo": {"id": 840, "patient_name": "John"},
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "library_id": 2,
            "caseinfo_id": 81,
            "caseinfo": {"id": 850, "patient_name": "Wick"},
        },
    ]
}

print(next((x for x in d["data"] if x["caseinfo"]["patient_name"] == "Wick"), None))
```

**Output:**

```
{'id': 2, 'library_id': 2, 'caseinfo_id': 81, 'caseinfo': {'id': 850, 'patient_name': 'Wick'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that you're looking for is in the nested dict:

```
dd = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "library_id": 1,
            "caseinfo_id": 80,
            "caseinfo":{
                "id": 840,
                "patient_name": "John"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "library_id": 2,
            "caseinfo_id": 81,
            "caseinfo":{
                "id": 850,
                "patient_name": "Wick"
            }
        }
    ]
}

for key, value in dd.items():
    for elem in value:
        for k,v in elem.items():
            if isinstance(v,dict):
                if 'Wick' in v.values():
                    print(elem)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'caseinfo_id': 81, 'library_id': 2, 'id': 2, 'caseinfo': {'id': 850, 'patient_name': 'Wick'}}
```